# Is there a way to set up parent-child view relationships in Rails 3, so as to add or subtract from a view instead of completely overriding it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, view, dry

Let's say I have a view, `views/layouts/home.html.haml`, and I am overriding it with a `themes/layouts/home.html.haml`.

In my Default view, I have:

`%p Some stuff.`

In my overriding view, I have:

`%p Some stuff.`

`%p More stuff!`

But now I'm repeating myself and maintaining two views for a fairly trivial addition.

In typical Ruby, I would do this by inheriting from a class, overriding a method, adding some behavior, and then calling `super` from the child class.

But views don't really have a parent they inherit from, they just get overridden. So is there any way I can set up a structure where I can declare that view inherits from another view, then call `super` from the child view and get the behavior of the parent view? E.g.

Default View:

`%p Some stuff.`

`yield :more_stuff`

Overriding View:

```
= content_for :more_stuff do
    %p More stuff!
super
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always render a partial inside the "child" view.

```
<%= render :partial => "account" %>
```

Read the full documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

Comment: This is definitely a valid solution, but for even moderately complex views I can see this resulting in having 3 or 4 partials per view (if you wanted to add things in a few different places on the page). You also get odd scenarios like having your `show.html.haml` view just being: `= render 'show'`, which seems wasteful. An inheritance-like way would be cleaner.

Comment: Of course it would! But things like you mentioned happens : in a new.html.haml you could have only = render 'form', which is okay.

Comment: You make a good point. I will accept your answer if no cleaner solutions are forthcoming. Thanks!